# Internet Explorer equivalent to window.performance.memory?

Tags: javascript, memory, browser

Does anyone know if IE has an equivalent to Chrome's `window.peformance.memory` property?

I am trying to find a way to analyse IE's memory performance in my application.

Running my js script using a Chrome browser is no problem, because Chrome has added a proprietary `memory` property to `window.performance` (see [window.performance.memory](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/performance) for more info).

The way I do it in Chrome is like this:

```
browser.driver.executeScript(function () {
   return window.performance.memory; // this is the problem, IE has no memory property
}).then(function (result) {

      logResults(result.jsHeapSizeLimit);
      logResults(result.usedJSHeapSize);
      logResults(result.totalJSHeapSize);

   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Internet explorer, use navigation.performance to make other types of measurements. More reference to speed.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance

For example: window.performance.now()

On this page you can see all the data that can be obtained with internet explorer or other browsers. You must enter with the internet explorer in the url, to see the data with the browser

https://browserleaks.com/javascript

Other option is using: CTRL+Shift+U keys [image]